# gunicorn worker process sharing Threads

Tags: flask, multiprocessing, gunicorn

I am starting my app with following gunicorn settings:

```
workers=5
threads=5
timeout=3600
preload_app=True
```

There was this one instance when the worker processes were sharing Threads.
Worker process `29213` and `29210` printed the same Thread : `NumberLong(140054350325504)`.

Is this possible since thread is a subset of a process. Or these threads are subsets of Master process and being shared by the child workers.